# How to make a question about a range?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, questions

There is a snippet of a text below where the number of speakers of different languages is not mentioned distinctly. It's just stated as "**from very large**" to "**very small**". I'd like to make a question regarding this information and get an answer like:

**They range in number from very large, with hundreds of millions of speakers, to very small, with fewer than 10 speakers.**

Original text:

> Native speakers of these languages range in number from very large,
>   with hundreds of millions of speakers, to very small, with fewer than
>   10 speakers.

Which question below is considered correct?

> Q1. How do the speakers of different languages range in number?
>
> Q2. To what lengths do the speakers of different languages range?
>
> Q3. In what number do the speakers of different languages range?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no simple question to guarantee that kind of answer.

However, something close would be:

> What is the distribution of native speakers of these languages, by count?

Answer (score 0):

I feel you’d be unlikely to get such an answer from a question because of the necessity to condense “native speakers of these languages” to simply “they”.

As a statement, it sounds quite erudite, and would more likely be written down in an essay or something, than found in discourse.

However, perhaps such an answer would be appropriate to something like:

> How many native speakers do these languages have?

But as mentioned by others, you couldn’t guarantee the answer would come in that form.

Answer (score -2):

The correct way to frame the question is -

What is the range of number of native speakers?

Comment: Answers should explain "why" - See the [Submitting Answers that merely answer the question](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/q/1117) discussion on meta.